# AutoResetEvent fire before signal

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, c#-4.0, autoresetevent

I've two similar methods to below ones. In the `MainThreadDoWork` method the loop is finish executing regardless of the autoResetEvent.Set() in the `OtherThreadWork` method. Any idea what's happening in this AutoResetEvent instance?

```
AutoResetEvent autoResetEvent = new AutoResetEvent(true);
private int count = 10;

private void MainThreadDoWork(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        if (autoResetEvent.WaitOne())
        {
            Console.WriteLine(i.ToString());
        }
    }
}

private void OtherThreadWork()
{
    autoResetEvent.Set();
    //DoSomething();
}
```

**EDIT**

Below is how actual OtherThreadWork looks like.

```
  private void OtherThreadWork()
    {
        if (textbox.InvokeRequired)
        {
            this.textbox.BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate() { OtherThreadWork(); }));
            autoResetEvent.Set();
        }
        else
        {
           // Some other code
        }
    }
```

Comment: Something is fishy here and I suspect that the actual code has some other problems. I ran this code on my machine and it blocks in the call to `WaitOne`.

Comment: @Tudor: I've posted the actual otherThreadWork method. Any idea what's happening there? Thanks!

Comment: `MainThreadDoWork` is executing on the UI thread?

Comment: So you are only executing the `Set` once? Because after the first invocation of `OtherThreadWork`, the next recursive call will not require `BeginInvoke`, so the else will execute. So are you expecting this code to block indefinitely?

Comment: You set the event *before* executing any of the OtherThreadWork code.  Calling WaitOne() on the UI thread is forbidden.  But supported, the CLR will pump a message loop.  Which in itself will make it look like the code isn't blocking.  Avoid re-inventing BackgroundWorker.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The boolean parameter passed to the `AutoResetEvent` constructor specifies if the event is created in the signalled state or not.

You're creating it already in the signalled state, so your first `WaitOne` won't block.

Try:

```
AutoResetEvent autoResetEvent = new AutoResetEvent( false );
```

Comment: Notice the loop with 10 iterations. After the first WaitOne, the waithandle will be set to unsignalled so it should only print a 0 and wait forever thereafter (given the sample code)

Comment: @Polity Yes - I was presuming this is just a sample. If he has 10 threads running `OtherThreadWork` then he will have missed signals too.

Comment: @NicholasButler: It was set to true purposely in order to execute the first iteration. My question is why it continues all the iterations without waiting otherThread's signal. There are only 2 threads running, main thread and one more.

Comment: A satisfied call to `AutoResetEvent.WaitOne()` will set the event's state to unsignalled. Subsequent calls to `WaitOne` will block until another thread signals the event. The code you've posted cannot exhibit the behaviour you've described. Are you sure "OtherThreadWork" does not call `autoResetEvent.Set()` multiple times in a loop?

Comment: @NicholasButler: MainThreadDoWork do something that trigger OtherThreadWork. I want to execute the loop one by one while the other thread handle each call. The issue is MainThreadDoWork straight away call all the 10 calls. OtherThreadWork has triggered only once. I have added logs there.

Comment: @NicholasButler: I've posted the actual otherThreadWork method. Any idea what's happening there? Thanks!

Comment: You could, maybe actually try to debug this?  When you put a breakpoint on the 'autoResetEvent.Set', what happens?  What does the stack look like at each call?  Where is 'autoResetEvent.Set' and OtherThreadWork() being called from?